# Installation magento weird result

Tags: magento2, magento-2.0

i have installed a fresh installation of magento via the FTP client, i have no SSH access to my hosting.

After transfering my data to the server, i ran the setup on my url and everything ran without any issues. Afterwards when i'm trying to open my Home page and Admin page, it looks like this:

[image]

[image]

What did I do wrong? Is there a step i have missed?

Thanks in advance.. :)

Comment: do you have mod_rewrite turned on? Also, check file permissions for the pub/static folder.

Answer (score 1):

your problem is that default luma theme is not loading on admin backend and frontend. just navigate to site root/bin and use command ./magento setup:static-content:deploy . it will generate css and js and deploy the theme files . this is not error.